# TYPO3 cms 8.7.x with Oracle DB - how to install

Tags: oracle, typo3

I try to install TYPO3 CMS 8.7.16 on a machine using OracleDB as database-server. Locally I have a Oracle XE - further it will run on Oracle Enterprise.

I got a hint on Slack to set

```
TYPO3_INSTALL_DB_DRIVER=oci8
TYPO3_INSTALL_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
TYPO3_INSTALL_DB_USER=typo3dbuser
TYPO3_INSTALL_DB_PASSWORD=apassword
TYPO3_INSTALLDB_PORT=1521
TYPO3_INSTALL_DB_DBNAME=typo3dbname
```

in /etc/environment. But this does not work - the Install Tools keeps asking for a MySQL database.

I tried to manually edit LocalConfiguration.php:

```
<?php
 return [
 'BE' => [
    'explicitADmode' => 'explicitAllow',
    'loginSecurityLevel' => 'rsa',
 ],
 'DB' => [
    'Connections' => [
        'Default' => [
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'driver' => 'oci8',
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'password' => 'apassword',
            'port' => 1521,
            'user' => 'typo3dbuser',
```

No it seams the InstallTool sees my DB, but I get two errors:

*Unable to create database
Database with name "kvtypo3" could not be created. Either your database name contains a reserved keyword or your database user does not have sufficient permissions to create it or the database already exists. Please choose an existing (empty) database, choose another name or contact administration.*

*Exception
An exception occured in driver: ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor*

User "typo3dbuser" has ALL privileges on this machine - ALL and ADMIN ;-)

Any hints how to configure it the right way? How and what to set for "SID"?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 return [
 'BE' => [
  'explicitADmode' => 'explicitAllow',
  'loginSecurityLevel' => 'rsa',
 ],
 'DB' => [
  'Connections' => [
    'Default' => [
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'driver' => 'oci8',
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'password' => 'apassword',
        'port' => 1521,
        'user' => 'typo3dbuser',
        'dbname' => 'XE'
```

Adding the last line did it!

**BUT:**

The tables were generated, but many errors were thrown like "ORA-00972: identifier is too long" for a statement like

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TX_EXTENSIONMANAGER_DOMAIN_MODEL_REPOSITORY_SEQ START WITH 1 MINVALUE 1 INCREMENT BY 1
```

and "ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object" for a statement like

```
CREATE INDEX "t3ver_oid" ON "backend_layout" ("t3ver_oid", "t3ver_wsid")
```

Trying to add a backend-user gives this error:

"Argument 1 passed to TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Schema\EventListener\SchemaColumnDefinitionListener::getDatabaseType() must be of the type string, null given, called in /home/schulzj/Projekte/PHP/kvtypo3/vendor/typo3/cms/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Database/Schema/EventListener/SchemaColumnDefinitionListener.php on line 42"

I think there are many issues with OracleDB and TYPO3 (i.e. because OracleDB does not know indexes and needs triggers/sequences for auto-increment-fields). Or something other...

If TYPO3 claims about to be compatible with OracleSQL - maybe if you use tables from there, but not for installing TYPO3 on it!

Comment: As defined, OracleXE (or <=12.1) can only handle database-table-names <30 chars. For TYPO3 more space is needed. I actually have no Oracle 12.2 to test. Maybe in autumn I can test this...